# For consuming a web service method using javascript in HTML,do we need to add any htc to the web directory?

Tags: web-services

For consuming a web service method using javascript in HTML,do we need to add any htc to the web directory?

Answer (score 0):

invoking a web service is basically the same as invoking a web page (with differences in the invoking method and the "what to do with the return" part ), so no, you shouldn't have to change anything

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your strategy. HTC files are considered outdated and aren't supported in Firefox, however they're also one of the quickest ways to get up and running.

I'd look into [jQuery's ajax](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) functionality as an alternative.